# javascript array.sort with undefined values

Tags: javascript, sorting, cross-browser

How does `Array.prototype.sort` handle undefined values in an array?

```
var array = [1,undefined,2,undefined,3,undefined,4];
var array2 = [];
array2[0] = 1;array2[2] = 2;array2[4] = 3;array2[6] = 4;
```

When calling `array.sort(function(l,r) { ... });` The values `undefined` are never passed in as `l` or `r`.

Can I guarantee that all the undefined values will always go to the end of the array for all browsers?

Would the following loop handle all the non `undefined` data in an array

```
array.sort();
for (var i = 0; array[i] !== undefined; i++) {
    // handle array
}
```

You may assume that no-one declared `undefined` as a variable.

Comment: In IE <=8, they will be removed from the array entirely. See: https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/issues/484#issuecomment-4055242

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you can safely assume `undefined` will get moved to the end of the array.

From [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> In JavaScript 1.2, this method no longer converts undefined elements to null; instead it sorts them to the high end of the array

From the [spec, 15.4.4.11](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf)
:

> Because non-existent property values always compare greater than undefined property values, and
>   undefined always compares greater than any other value, undefined property values always sort to the end of the result,
>   followed by non-existent property values.

Comment: Thank you. Its not neccesary for them to exist merely for there to be no "gaps" containing undefined values in the array. Please do add some kind of section or page number to the link for the spec.

Answer (score 0):

all undefined values will go to the end of the array regardless of their order in declaration. (at least this is how it works in chrome's js engine)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the undefined values will fall to the bottom of the list. Here's some sample code to show you what happens:

```js
var a = [1, undefined, 2, undefined, 3, undefined, 4];
a.sort();
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  console.log(a[i]);
}
```

This is, of course, the default behavior of JavaScript. If you overwrite the default behavior then only you will know.