# OrderBy pipe in angular 4

Tags: angular, sorting, typescript

I'm trying to write sorting pipe according to code in this link:
http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1211/angular-2-search-and-sort-with-ngfor-repeater-with-example
Although I have trouble with dealing with undefined values. My pipe works correctly on columns where there are not any undefined values. But when there is at least one undefined value in column pipe work in a strange way.
My code below:

html template:

```
*ngFor="let candidate of filteredList | orderBy:{property: column, direction: direction}"
```

in html template to choose column and direction eg:

```
<th class="pointer" nowrap="nowrap" (click)="sort('lastName')">{{ 'candidates.candidates' | translate }}
      <i class="fa" [ngClass]="{'fa-sort': column != 'lastName',
                        'fa-sort-asc': (column == 'lastName' && !isDesc),
                        'fa-sort-desc': (column == 'lastName' && isDesc) }"
         aria-hidden="true"> </i></th>
```

order-by.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'orderBy'
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(candidates: Array<object>, args?: any): any {
    candidates = candidates || [];
    return candidates.sort(function (a, b) {

      if (a[args.property] === b[args.property]) {
        return 0;
      }
      if (a[args.property] === '' || a[args.property] === null || typeof a[args.property] === 'undefined') {
        return 1;
      }
      if (b[args.property] === '' || b[args.property] === null || typeof b[args.property] === 'undefined') {
        return -1;
      }
      if (a[args.property] < b[args.property]) {
        console.log(a[args.property] + ' wartosc property');
        return -1 * args.direction;
      } else if (a[args.property].toLowerCase() > b[args.property].toLowerCase()) {
        return 1 * args.direction;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

component.ts:

```
public sort(property: string) {
    this.isDesc = !this.isDesc;
    this.column = property;
    this.direction = this.isDesc ? 1 : -1;
  }
```

I was trying many different approaches but none of then was worinkg fine.

Comment: Related: Just worth a read :) https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: I'm aware that it can be moved to component itself, but in my case that's not an option - it has to be this pipe

Comment: It does not have to be in component, it can be a shared service as well if other components need the same pipe. But yes, I just wanted to point out that link if by any chance you weren't aware of this recommendation. But good that you were aware! :)

Comment: could you describe the "strange way" your pipe works with undefined values?  Can you add a set of data to try to reproduce?

Comment: @PierreMallet it is changing the order of items but not in a correct way. Lets say that i have an array in which some objects have values: 10, 20, undefined, 30. When i press sorting button it gives me result: 10, undefined, 20, 30, next time undefined 20, 10, 30 and so on .. There are not 2 results (asc and desc) but for example 4 "random" which are repeating

Comment: I try to reproduce with stackBlitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n5qagl) but can't reproduce the behavior you mention. Is there something I'm missing? ( i implemented all the logic in app.component.ts )

Comment: I don't think that anything is missing in logic. This is the whole logic to this sorting feature.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use lodash for sorting?

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

@Pipe({
    name: 'orderBy'
})
export class OrderByPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(array: Array<{}>, args: string[]): Array<string> | Array<{}> {

        array = array || [];

        if (typeof args === 'undefined' || args.length !== 2) {
            return array;
        }

        const [key, direction] = args;

        if (direction !== 'ASC' && direction !== 'DESC') {
            return array;
        }

        return _.orderBy(array, (item:any) => item[key], direction.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Comment: And how should I use it in html template so that it works correctly? Could you help me out?

Comment: in your html template,  add the pipe as | orderBy:['lastName', 'DESC']

Comment: I have implemented your code, but it's not working correclty. It sorts columns where there aren' t any undefined values correcly, but columns where there are some undefinded values are sorted onlu once (despite clicking on button to sort in a different way nothing happens - i can sort it again only after i use sort button on column where there aren' t any undefined values) plus result of this sorting isn't correct - as it was before in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's because JavaSctipt `Array.sort` function will always put undefined to the end of array and the undefined values aren't passed to *compareFunction* as *a and b arguments*.

See this post for more details: [javascript array.sort with undefined values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783242/javascript-array-sort-with-undefined-values)

Comment: I see your point, but why they seem to be sorted randomly? Not i a specific order? And how should I sort them?

Answer (score 0):

It will work even for `null`, `undefined` `''` and any type of data type like number string bool:

```
transform(arr: any[], property: any, direction: number): any[] | null {

    if(!arr || arr?.length == 0)
      return arr;

      arr.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      let v1 = a[property]?? '';
      let v2 = b[property]?? '';
      if(v1 < v2)
        return 1 * direction;
      else if(v1 > v2)
        return -1 * direction;
      else 
        return 0 * direction;
    });
    return arr;
  }
```