# Why does Array.sort discriminate NaN vs undefined even after coercing the value in the comparator?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand why the output of the code below separates the `NaN` to the beginning of the array and the `undefined` values to the end of the array.  I'm coercing the `NaN` and `undefined` to 0 so I would expect for them to be collocated (grouped) together.

```
[9, undefined, NaN, undefined].sort(
  function (a, b) {
    // coercing NaN or undefined to 0
    const first = (Number.isNaN(a) || a === undefined) ? 0 : a;
    const second = (Number.isNaN(b) || b === undefined) ? 0 : b;

    if (first < second) {
      return -1;
    } else if (first > second) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
)
```

actual output is

```
[
  NaN,
  9,
  undefined,
  undefined
]
```

expected output would be

```
[
  9,
  NaN,
  undefined,
  undefined
]
// or some variant where the NaN and undefined are grouped together
[
  NaN,
  undefined,
  undefined
  9,
]
```

### update

From the [linked duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783242/javascript-array-sort-with-undefined-values), I kind of understand that `undefined` values have a special rule applied to them (where they are pushed to the end of the array), but it still seems odd that this rule of handling `undefined` values get applied before the comparator can have a chance at processing the `undefined` value.

Does anyone know if it's a pre-filter that's going on when Array.sort is invoked?  Akin to

```
[undefined, 9]
  .filter(x => x !== undefined)
  .sort(...)
```

In which case, would it be less processing to simply remove the `undefined` values a priori, if I needed to call `Array.sort` multiple times on an array containing `undefined` values?  I'm trying to get a sense of how the internals of Array.sort is behaving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do the `array.sort` in which first they simply ignore `undefined` and second you convert `NaN` to `0`, so obviously in sort `0` comes first and `9` is second

> In `array.sort`, all `non-undefined` array elements are sorted according
>   to the return value of the compare function (all `undefined` elements
>   are sorted to the end of the array, with no call to function)

More information : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description

```js
var test = [9, undefined, NaN, undefined].sort(
  function (a, b) {
    // coercing NaN or undefined to 0
    const first = (Number.isNaN(a) || a === undefined) ? 0 : a;
    const second = (Number.isNaN(b) || b === undefined) ? 0 : b;
    
    console.log(first, second);

    if (first < second) {
      return -1;
    } else if (first > second) {
      return 1;
    } else {   
      return 0;
    }
  }
);

console.log(test);
```

Comment: I updated my question.  Do you know how the `undefined` values are ignored?

Comment: Are you want to remove `undefined` values from array

Comment: Sorry. I don't fully understand your comment.  If your question is: "Are you wanting to remove undefined values from an array?"  Then, my answer is no.  My expectation with `Array.sort` was that it would apply the comparator function to _every_ value in the array (even `undefined` values).

Comment: `undefined` are sorted to end, please https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description