# What are "non-existent property values" in ECMA spec for ARRAY:SORT

Tags: javascript, language-lawyer

In an answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783242/javascript-array-sort-with-undefined-values) (which otherwise I can fully understand/etc), there'a this curious quite:

> From the spec, 15.4.4.11 :
>
> > Because **non-existent property values** always compare greater than
> > undefined property values, and undefined always compares greater than
> > any other value, undefined property values always sort to the end of
> > the result, **followed by non-existent property values**.

I've checked in the [latest version available now](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort) and it's "note 1" at the end of `sort` spec, and it's basically the same as it was when that answer from 2011 was written.

Regarding `undefined property values always sort to the end of the result, followed by non-existent property values` -- how can it be? what are "non-existent property values"(*)? if we write `a.foo` and `a` doesn't have such property, we'll get `undefined`, so how can it be differentiated?

The `sort` is called either without any parameter, or with a comparer-style function, and in the latter case, it's our function, and we're bound to read the non-existent property and get `undefined`.. The `sort` can't inspect the object's keys for us to decide whever an inspected object has a property or not (in contrast to i.e. certain underscore/lodash helpers where you define a 'path' like i.e. `pluck` or `get`). I just dont see how we could trigger this "non-existent property values" case at all.

(*) I've found something that looks like a definition of this term [here](https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-invariants-of-the-essential-internal-methods):

> A non-existent property is a property that does not exist as an own property on a non-extensible target.
> (...)
> If the target is non-extensible and P is non-existent, then all future
> calls to [[GetOwnProperty]] (P) on the target must describe P as
> non-existent (i.e. [[GetOwnProperty]] (P) must return undefined).

This must-describe-as-nonexistent and must-return-undefined seem to support my doubt.

I've also noticed that the pseudo-code for `SortIndexedProperties` (used to define `sort`) actually contains bits like `3.b. Let kPresent be ? HasProperty(obj, Pk).`. So maybe that `non-existent property` part in `sort` spec meant to cover some case like the array being mutated by the comparer function and certain keys are removed from it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-existent property on an array will be "included" when sorting only if the array is sparse. Here's an example, look at the comments:

```js
const arr = []; // 0-length array
arr[2] = 'foo'; // Turns into 3-length array. Does not have own properties 0 or 1
arr.sort();

console.log(arr[0]); // Sort result includes a value from defined property
console.log(arr.hasOwnProperty(1)); // But not from the sparse elements
console.log(arr.length); // But the array will have the same length as originally
```

As you can see, the properties that didn't exist on the original sparse array are "sorted" to the end of the array, and don't exist on the resulting sorted array either, except for the `.length` of the sorted array. It started out as an array with a length of 3 and only one own-property, and ended up as an array with a length of 3 and only one own-property (but with that own-property at a different index).

> if we write a.foo and a doesn't have such property, we'll get undefined, so how can it be differentiated?

It's equivalent to a `.hasOwnProperty` check:

```js
const obj1 = {};
const obj2 = { foo: undefined };
console.log(obj1.hasOwnProperty('foo'));
console.log(obj2.hasOwnProperty('foo'));

const arr1 = ['abc'];
const arr2 = [, 'def']; // sparse array
console.log(arr1.hasOwnProperty(0));
console.log(arr2.hasOwnProperty(0));
```

Best approach to all of this - never use sparse arrays to begin with, they're too confusing.

Comment: This `arr[2] = 'foo'; // Turns into 3-length array. Does not have own properties 0 or 1` was the case I was missing. I forgot about 'spare' variation, and didn't know that 0&1 will not be considered 'existing' after this assignement (since that conflicts with length, and my view on the array and sort() was totally length-centric, like good old contiguous arrays in C-style models). Thank you very much!